# Check if string contains another C

Tags: c, string, winapi, unicode-string

Now i have this code, but it always set null

```
UNICODE_STRING str;
char *cmp = "Hello";

RtlInitUnicodeString (&str, L"Hello world!");

if( ( strstr((char * )str.Buffer, cmp) ) != NULL)
{
   // cmp founded in str.
}
else
{
   // cmp not founded in str. Always here, but why??
}
```

Can you explain me why strstr in my case always null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're searching for a multi-byte string in a Unicode one. Use `wcsstr`:

```
wchar * cmp = L"Hello";
wcsstr(str.Buffer, cmp);
```

You were hiding this by casting to `char *`.

---

You should really ask another question for your second request, but you might write a function like this:

```
void make_string_lower(WCHAR * str)
{
  while(str[0] != '\0') {
    if(iswalpha(str[0] && !iswlower(str[0]))) {
      str[0] = towlower(str[0]);
    }

    str++;
  }
}
```

Alternatively use `_wcslwr`.

Comment: what i should do to fix that?

Comment: (offtop) can you please give me a function which can replace WСHAR string to lower case?

Comment: @user1262425: Added some code. Didn't test it, but hopefully it'll give you some inspiration.

Comment: This code is technically incorrect as UNICODE_STRINGs are not guaranteed to be null terminated. Ideally, you'd need to convert the buffer back into a null terminated wide character, then compare it.