# Convert WCHAR string to lower case C

Tags: c, string, lowercase

I have a code:

```
WCHAR * cmp = L"TEST";
```

Need a function which would return this string in lower case!

Thanks!

Comment: Good luck modifying that string literal with a predictable result.

Comment: Here's a function that returns the string in lower case: `WCHAR *lowerCase(void) { return L"test"; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting wide char string to lowercase in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614595/converting-wide-char-string-to-lowercase-in-c)

Comment: I already answered this for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9656257/712358. However, you can't pass `cmp` into that function since it would be read-only.

Comment: Mike Kwan, i tried to use your function, but compiler throws error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_iswlower

Comment: @user1262425: Did you `#include <ctype.h>` or `#include <wchar.h>`?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the `WCHAR`, you're presumably using (some version of) VC++. In this case, you want to use [`_wcslwr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkxwh33z.aspx) or [`_wcslwr_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y889wzfw.aspx). You normally do *not* want to use `tolower` or `toupper` on wide character strings.

Comment: He probably wants to use `_wcslwr` :P You also might want to add that `towlower` and `towupper` are Unicode equivalents of the two multibyte functions you talk about.

Comment: @MikeKwan: _wcslwr is for wide character strings, not multitbyte strings. I considered mentioning towlower, but I don't recall the MS compiler including it (though I haven't looked in a while -- it probably does now).

Comment: I swear I read `_wcsupr` in your original answer! `towlower` is included in `<ctype.h>` or `<wchar.h>`.

Comment: Thanks! I added <ctype.h> and <wchar.h> but now it throw:
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_iswctype
. I try to add <wctype.h> but this file is not included to WDK

Comment: The WDK has a lot of chunks missing from the usual SDK.

Comment: `std::transform(upperStr, &upperStr[sizeof upperStr/ sizeof(wchar_t)], upperStr, ::towupper);` is it legit?

Comment: @Sandburg: yes and no. It will work for some strings, but `towupper` can only give you back a single character of output for a single character of input, so (for example) if you pass it the German `ß` character, the closest upper-case equivalent requires two characters (`"SS"`), so there's no way for it to really handle that well.